# I am trying to format my pc but my bootable ext-hdd is not working.Why?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, formatting

I am right now using Kali Linux on my laptop. My ext-HDD is set to 1st priority in BIOS and USB boot is enabled. I installed my Windows 10 ISO with "Universal USB Installer" but I can't format my laptop.
My ext-HDD has 2 partitions : 1-personal data part 2-format part.

Why am I facing such an issue?

Comment: Does your computer have Secure Boot enabled?  BIOS setting.

Comment: let me check it and reply back.

Comment: @John switched to uefi mode.
Secure Boot [Enabled]
Secure Boot Status [Disabled]
Still having issues and not recognizing ext-hdd.